# Looking for example of Selenium application as a Maven project in Eclipse, using TestNG as runner cum reporting tool

Tags: java, selenium, testng, maven-3, testng-eclipse

I created a maven project of Selenium application to test an Angular web site using **ngWebDriver** in eclipse. In the pom.xml file, I declared **selenium-java, testng, ngWebDriver, WebDriverManager, assertJ,**etc., dependencies. Added TestNG library dependency to the project. Since it is a maven project, all my test classes with test methods are placed inside **src/test/java** folder, instead of **src/main/java** folder of the project. I declared test suite in the TestNG config file **testng.xml**. Inside that suite, test classes were declared. Since I need to pass parameters to the class methods, I declared **parameter name, value pairs**, just above the class declaration. Now my question(s) are...

1. Should I maintain this Eclipse project as TestNG project and create maven run configuration to run it ? OR
2. Should I maintain this Eclipse project as maven project and run it as TestNG suite with classes ??

Comment: I think that completely depends on your needs and what you want to achieve with this testing project.

Comment: I totally agree with @AppuMistri. However, if you want to checkout sample project, please visit: https://github.com/prernapal13/JWAF

Comment: Here is a Selenium/TestNG template that may be useful: https://github.com/Ardesco/Selenium-Maven-Template

Comment: @Ardesco I find the zip file useful.